# Условие для бронирования билта на маршрут

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream

```
Саратов - Воронеж - Тула - Москва
   0         1       2       3
```

Place: 43

```
Саратов - Воронеж
   0         1
                  
Саратов - Тула
   0        2

Саратов - Москва,
   0        3


Воронеж- Тула
  1       2

Воронеж - Москва    
  1         3


Тула   - Москва
  2        3
```

Покупаем билет на

```
Саратов - Тула 
   0        2
```

Наше 43 Место должны быть забронированые для следующих маршрутов:

```
Саратов-Воронеж,
   0       1

Саратов-Тула,
   0      2

Саратов-Москва
   0      3

Воронеж-Тула,
   1      2

Воронеж-Москва,
   1      3
```

Но должно быть доступно для бронирования для:

```
Тула-Москва
  2    3
```

есть класc Route у него есть два поля entranceStop и exitStop:

```
public class Route {

   //fields
   private int entranceStop;

   private int exitStop;
}
```

С помощью этих полей я стараюсь сделать проверку есть ли место забронировано для выбранного маршрута или нет.
Код который проверяет:

```
 private SeatDTO checkBookedSeat(Route route, Seat seat) {
    SeatDTO seatDTO = convertToDTO(seat);
    if (!seat.getTickets().isEmpty()){
        boolean isBooked = seat.getTickets()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(ticket -> {
                    int lastStop = seat.getTrip().getStops().size() - 1;
                    boolean isFullWay = ticket.getRoute().getEntranceStop() == 0 && ticket.getRoute().getExitStop() == lastStop;
                    boolean validStart = ticket.getRoute().getEntranceStop() <= route.getEntranceStop();
                    boolean stopPoint = ticket.getRoute().getExitStop() >= route.getExitStop();
                    return isFullWay || (validStart && stopPoint); //здесь надо заменить условие так чтобы оно работало для всех вышеупомянутых условий
                });
        if (isBooked) {
            seatDTO.setBooked(true);
        }
    }
    return seatDTO;
}
```

Сейчас условие работает только для:

```
Саратов-Воронеж,
   0       1
Саратов-Тула,
   0      2

Воронеж- Тула
  1       2
```

Надо еще сделать для того чтобы работало для:

```
Саратов - Москва,
   0        3

Воронеж-Москва
   1       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данных условиях мы не можем забронировать место если оно занбронировано внутри определенного интервала. Точка начала стартового маршрута должна выходить из этого интервала.

```
seat.getTickets()
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(ticket -> {
         boolean ifRouteStartsBefore = 
              route.getEntranceStop() < ticket.getRoute().getEntranceStop() && // если новые маршрут начинается раньше записанного маршрута
              route.getExitStop() <= ticket.getRoute().getEntranceStop() && // если маршрут заканчивается до начала записанного маршрута или тогда же, когда и заканчивается записаный маршрут.
              route.getExitStop() != route.getEntranceStop(); // если начало и конец нового маршрута не совпадают

         boolean ifRouteStartsAfter = // проверяем начинается ли маршрут после существующей записи
              route.getEntranceStop() >= ticket.getRoute().getExitStop() &&
              route.getExitStop() != route.getEntranceStop(); // если начало и конец нового маршрута не совпадают

         return ifRouteStartsBefore || ifRouteStartsAfter;
});
```

что-то вроде этого, если я все верно понял. Еще надо добавить учет места, как мне кажется, к сожалению ваш код не полный, написал исходя из вашего кода. Писал не в IDE могут быть ошибки.

Ну и я не учел условия, когда начало позже конца, надеюсь у вас на это есть проверка в других частях программы.

Comment: к сожалению, эти условия делают забронированным то место которое должно быть как раз не забронировано

Comment: так инвертируйте `return !ifRouteStartsBefore || !ifRouteStartsAfter;`

Comment: Спасибо, голова уже не думает :)